# A simple exchange for using usr/pwd from another backend in Aspnetcore2.2

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

How do I create a simple aspnetcore(2.2)+ solution that uses a backend to only authenticate users?

I should not manage users and I can specify the API so it should have, hopefully, only 1 method `IsAuthenticated(email,password)`.

I started out with the boiler plate

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<MyIdentityUser>()
    .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
    .AddUserStore<MyUserStore>();
```

with the simplest possible implementation of
`MyIdentityUser` and
`MyUserStore : IUserStore<MyIdentityUser>, IUserPasswordStore<MyIdentityUser>, IUserEmailStore<MyIdentityUser>`
but it does too much as I had to do (faux) implementations of `FindByNameAsync`, `GetPasswordHashAsync`, `GetUserIdAsync`, `GetUserNameAsync` and more.

I *guess* it is the `AddDefaultIdentity` method that is to blame (well... it is me to blame really as I still see me as superior to computers) as [I guess the "Default"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#adddefaultidentity-and-addidentity) in the method name means that I will have a backend that manages everything.

I have read [MSDN:Introduction to Identity on ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) and [Configure ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?view=aspnetcore-2.2) but they are either too oriented around replacing EF-and-everything or my reading-docs-skillz are not good enough. Similarly I have scoured the internet but it seems my google-fu is not strong enough.

**UPDATE**

Unmentioned above I especially had to implement `GetPasswordHashAsync` which should return the same hashing algorithm as is used when hashing the user input (viewmodel). If I can override that hashing algorithm I can either send plain text to the backend (hmm) or ask for the algorithm and implement it myself (better).
As it is now `GetPasswordHashAsync` has to return [a hash in a special format](https://andrewlock.net/exploring-the-asp-net-core-identity-passwordhasher/) with a leading character telling which of two algoritms was used.

Is the solution to override (how) the algorithm used for the viewmodel? If so, how?
I see articles about setting a new `PasswordHasher` for a `UserManager` but I cannot get my head around how to inject it into the flow.

Comment: What do you mean by '...that uses a backend to only authenticate users' ? What exactly it should do ? Authenticate users using login/pwd ? What type of auth, jwt, cookie ? Add more details regarding the authentication flow.

Comment: So, for argument's sake, you have a single authentication API `IsAuthenticated(email,password)` and you want to know how to use-but-override (use-but-not-use?) ASP.NET Identity Core so that it rests on said authentication API and nothing else? That probably won't work, since Identity is going to want to know something about, you know, the *identity* of the user. That's why everything's built around generics that take some sort of user object. Is your user identity just a username?

Comment: @Fabjan The plan is to have a "regular" call, like a webapi or rest call from the web server to the backend. I take for granted they have a secure protocol. So I tried to implement `IUserStore` and just overload some sort of "IsUserAuthenticated" method (which does not exist it turned out). But then I had to overload a whole bunch of methods that had to do with user management and not authorisation and got cold feet; suspected I was on the wrong track by for instance calling `AddUserStore` and by that implying I should take care of user management.

Comment: @Fabjan and @Marc-L : I updated with the method `GetPasswordHashAsync` that broke my flow.

Comment: Upvoted because I completely understand what you mean by documentation being tightly coupled with EF. Had issues for really long time understanding Identity because of it

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not the responsibility of IUserPasswordStore to hash the password, so you don't need to put your hash algorithm there. The responsibility of IUserPasswordStore is only how to set and get the hashed password from your Identity User (MyIdentityUser).

Take a look at the implementation of GetPasswordHashAsync in the UserStoreBase, it is simply return the user.PasswordHash, that's all.

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/bfec2c14be1e65f7dd361a43950d4c848ad0cd35/src/Identity/Extensions.Stores/src/UserStoreBase.cs

So if you implement IUserPasswordStore it does not mean that you have to have your own Password Hasher.

The one that responsible for hashing the password is IPasswordHasher. If you want to have your own Password Hasher you can implement it yourself.

```
    public class MyPasswordHasher : IPasswordHasher<MyIdentityUser>
    {
        public string HashPassword(MyIdentityUser user, string password)
        {
            ...
        }

        public PasswordVerificationResult VerifyHashedPassword(MyIdentityUser user, string hashedPassword, string providedPassword)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

For the default password hasher you can find it here,

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/bfec2c14be1e65f7dd361a43950d4c848ad0cd35/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/PasswordHasher.cs

And register it for DI in startup.cs, so that the UserManager will be using your own custom Password Hasher. Or in other word this will inject your Password Hasher into the flow.

```
services.AddScoped<IPasswordHasher<MyIdentityUser>, MyPasswordHasher>();
```

And also take a look at the UserManager class, this is where the IUserPasswordStore and IPasswordHasher interacting. Inside the UserManager you'll find the following code

```
passwordStore.SetPasswordHashAsync(user, PasswordHasher.HashPassword(newPassword)).WithCurrentCulture();
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` does take username and password and logs you in. It takes two more fields (bools), the first is "is persistent" which you can mark as false in your case and the second is lockout. This returns `SignInResult` which you can then use to check if the login was successful by using `result.Succeeded`.

```
var result = signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(username, pass, true, true);
return result.Succeeded;
```